# Tevilat keilim - one item definitely needs a beracha, the others dont

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, keilim-purity

When there is a safek regarding whether to do tevilat keilim on an item we generally don't say a beracha when tovelling the item since this beracha is d'rabbanan i.e., tovel without a beracha.

However, I have been advised to take an item that **does** require a beracha and simply 'use this beracha' to additionally tovel the other 'safek tevilah' items. In this way we remove ourselves from a safek.

In a case where only one item requires tevillah with a beracha, and where you also tovel other keilim that don't require tevillah with a beracha, is the beracha על טבילת **כלי** or על טבילת **כלים**? (see relevant [Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh De'ah, 120: 3)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.120.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Meaning: Since only one item requires the beracha do we say כלי  or do we recognise that other things are being tovelled as well and say כלים?

Comment: Not everyone agrees there is a distinct singular form to the blessing, so probably it's safe to use the "plural" form (since anyway plenty of authorities think that's the ideal one always)